# IntelliJ - print my keymap

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a way to print **my** keymap (IntelliJ IDEA)?

Maybe a plugin?
I couldn't find a way and I don't want to type all shortcuts manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7066?pr=idea) will export your keymap to a .PDF file, which you can then print.

Comment: the key map is not working on latest community edition: 14.1.5 running on mac

Answer (score 2):

In /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/resources.jar all the keymaps are in directory keymaps as XML-File. So someone could create a stylesheet for this to print them out. However, if you modify them, in $HOME/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea2017.1/keymaps/ there are the modifications, however they refer to the basic keymaps as parent.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [Keymap Reference](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/keymap-reference.html) from their site - this is the default mapkey. You will also find the mapkey for Linux and OSX in there.

Unfortunately, there is no such plug-ins. You can try to change the PDF file default hot-keys, it will be faster than creating it yourself.